# Capture/suppress raw C output in R function call

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am reading a remote NetCDF file using the `ncdf4` package. The command looks like this:

```
library(ncdf4)
url <- "http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.WORLDCLIM/.AMT/X/%28-165.000000%29VALUE/X2/%288.211400%29VALUE/Y/%2845.000000%29VALUE/Y2/%28-6.032500%29VALUE/dods"
nc <- nc_open(url)
```

The command runs without error. *However*, it spits out a bunch of output to the R console as it does so, which no combination of `sink`, `captureOutput`, etc. is able to capture or suppress. I think the reason is that the error messages are printed directly to `stderr` by C code that `ncdf4` package calls.

My question is: Is there any way to suppress this output from within an R session? I am open to extremely hacky and/or potentially dangerous solutions.